# How to reserve resource for a certain task in spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, mesos

I have two kinds of tasks in spark : A and B
In spark.scheduler.pool, I have two pools: APool and BPool.

I want task A to be executed aways in APool while B is in BPool.

The resources in APool is preserved to A. 
Because task B may take too much resources to execute. Every time when B is executing, A needs to wait. I want no matter when the task is submitted, there will always be some resource for A to execute.

---

I am using spark with java in standalone mode. I submit the job like javaRDD.map(..).reduce... The javaRDD is a sub-clesse extended form JavaRDD. Task A and B have different RDD class like ARDD and BRDD. They run in the same spark application.

The procedure is like: The app start up -> spark application created, but no job runs -> I click "run A" on the app ui, then ARDD will run. -> I click "run B" on the app ui, then BRDD will run in the same spark application as A.

Comment: Would it not be enough to request resources according to these requirements? Don't submit multiple tasks of the same type concurrently, and make sure that tasks A and B request resources according to the correct ratios...

Comment: t tasks A and B request resources according to the correct ratios  ---How to set the ratio? This is what I am asking.